# How to send a POST request to an API on localhost in R

Tags: r, json, api, post, httr

Getting 404 not found status code when trying to send a POST request to an API on localhost from R using httr package with a JSON body.

The request is successful from Postman and python using requests package

Is there a way to resolve this issue

App-

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    import uvicorn

    app = FastAPI()

    @app.get("/test")
    async def get_test():
        return "Hello"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=4000, debug=True)
```

Request from R-

```
    r <- GET("http://127.0.0.1:4000/test", verbose())
```

```
-> GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/test HTTP/1.1
-> Host: 127.0.0.1:4000
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3.1 httr/1.4.2
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
<- date: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 11:18:40 GMT
<- server: uvicorn
<- content-length: 22
<- content-type: application/json
```

Comment: I do it all the time, so the problem must be in your code. Would you care to share it?

Comment: I have added the code with GET request, which results in same problem

Comment: Is this windows? Are either python and/or R running in a VM, docker-container, or within WSL?

Comment: Yes, this is on windows. All the codes running on local

Comment: @lakshman I guess by now you've probably solved this issue, may I ask you what command are you using to start the `uvicorn` server?